# How does udp receive message if it doesn´t have a connection?

Tags: udp, ip, transmission

Something i couldn´t get wrapped around my head is how UDP works. If it doesn´t have a connection, how does the end point get a response after sending the packets? Is it always listening to the address he sent?

Comment: It can always *receive* at the IP:port it is bound to. It is connected to the network but there is no logical connection to the peer. 'Real-time' has a specific meaning in computing, and this isn't it.

Comment: @user207421 So the socket is always active? If not, how do i know when is the datagram coming?